# SQL Server 2017: update 2 columns in a table simultaneously with data from another table doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2017. I have a problem with an update of a table using values from another table.

I use the following setup:

Table "Main":

| ID | Val1 | Val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | NULL | NULL |

Table "Val":

| MainID | Type | Val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | 1 | 345.67 |
| 42 | 2 | 567.89 |

Then I want to update (in 1 statement) the Val1 and Val2 columns in "Main" with the values from "Val":

```
UPDATE m
SET m.Val1 = CASE WHEN v.Type = '1' THEN v.Val ELSE m.Val1 END,
    m.Val2 = CASE WHEN v.Type = '2' THEN v.Val ELSE m.Val2 END
FROM Main m 
INNER JOIN Val v ON m.ID = v.MainID
```

`Val1` via Type 1 should be updated to 345.67 and `Val2` via Type 2 should be updated to 567.89, so that the desired result should look as follows:

Table "Main":

| ID | Val1 | Val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | 345.67 | 567.89 |

However, the actual result is:

Table "Main":

| ID | Val1 | Val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | 345.67 | NULL |

What am I doing wrong here? Any ideas?

Please also take advantage of the SQLFiddle example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ab9bf0/14

I know there are many similar questions on Stackoverflow already, but always doing something slightly different, so unfortunately they were of no help to me. If you found one that might solve my issue I'm more than happy to check it out.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: As written, the issue is which of the two rows will be used for your update? You don't know and there is no way to know but only ONE will be used (not both). This is a common logic mistake in an update involving a 1:M relationship.

Comment: Excellent remark, SMor, thanks very much. Wasn't aware of that behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use sub-query. Calculate the GROUP BY query in the sub-query and the join to Main table

```
UPDATE m
SET    m.Val1 = v.Val1,
       m.Val2 = v.Val2
FROM   Main m 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT MainID,
           Val1 = MAX(CASE WHEN Type = '1' THEN Val END),
           Val2 = MAX(CASE WHEN Type = '2' THEN Val END)
    FROM   Val
    GROUP BY MainID
 ) v ON m.ID = v.MainID;
```

Comment: Thanks very much indeed, Squirrel. Works as expected. Didn't know that you first need to summarize the values before you get 1 record you can use for update.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way to do it is using `pivot`:

```
update main
set val1=[1], val2 = [2] 
from Val
pivot (
    max(val) for type in ([1],[2])  
    ) p
where main.ID=p.MainID
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Yván, that's a good approach and very helpful. But I think, just by personal taste, I'd prefer Squirrel's answer.